# Integral with Dirac delta.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}\delta_k$.
Calculte the integral :
$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} [2^{-x^2-y^2}+\frac{3}{4} ] dL^1(x) \otimes d\mu(y)$. Where $[a]$-floor.

Can I write :
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[2^{-x^2-y^2}+\frac{3}{4} ] dL^1(x) \right) d\mu(y)$?

Comment: Yes you can.  That's Fubini's (or Tonelli's) theorem.

Comment: Ok :) But I don't know how to start...

Comment: Notice that $$ \left[ 2^{-x^2-y^2} + \frac{3}{4} \right] = \begin{cases} 1, & x^2+y^2\leq 2 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: Yes.. You're right.